# Gemfire client region to get updates from server

Tags: gemfire

I have a Gemfire server region (distributed) and a local region (caching proxy) configured this way:

```
<client-cache>
<pool name="client" subscription-enabled="true">     
    <locator host="localhost" port="13489" />
</pool>

<region name="customers" refid="CACHING_PROXY">
    <region-attributes>
        <subscription-attributes interest-policy="all"/>
        <!--<subscription-attributes interest-policy="cache-content"/>-->
    </region-attributes>
</region>
</client-cache>
```

When I'm getting a value from a client region and the key is unknown on the client - it is fetched from the server. After that, however, if the server value changes - the new value is not propagated to client, even when subscription-attributes are set.

What is the misconfiguration here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have all changes pushed into your local cache you would need to remove the subscription attributes tag and instead, leave subscription-enabled=true on the pool, and then programmatically call the region.registerInterest API [GemFire JavaDoc](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/javadocs/japi/index.html) to actually cause the server to start delivering change notifications to your client.

As a good starting point, I would suggest

`region.registerInterestRegex(".*", InterestResultPolicy.NONE, false, false)`

This will ensure that you only receive "fresh" values and will take advantage of local cache for repeated retrievals but will not attempt to put all values in memory.  However, there are quite a few options for interest registration so you will want to consult the javadoc.

As an additional note, CACHING_PROXY is often combined with some eviction mechanism to ensure that the size of the local cache does not grow indefinitely.

Also, the subscription attributes inside the region tag actually apply to server side configuration, not the client side.  Even on the server side it is not ususally necessary  to configure the subscription-attributes because the server side region shortcuts (PARTITION, REPLICATE, etc. ) generally configure them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. Can I also assume that the client will get events for every key in the region, even those that were never stored/needed on this client?

Comment: Yes.  The client will get an event for ever cache update.  Whether it receives the actual value and stores it in the cache will depend on that last parameter of registerInterest but either way you get an event (if you had a CacheListener on the region it would fire).